# Split browser screen into three sections (Google Maps API)

Tags: google-maps, split, screen, fullscreen

I'm trying to split browser screen into three sections, each one will show a different Map location from Google Maps API. Here's the image link so you can see how i need to split the screen. Does anyone have any CSS/HTML suggestions?

https://meocloud.pt/link/083af416-c99f-4681-bc57-8124b9899158/maps.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to know a little bit of **CSS** to display the maps in this way...

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var map,map2, map3;

    function initialize(condition) {
    // create the map
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.1255275,-73.6964801),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var myOptions2 = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.1255275,-73.6964801),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }

        var myOptions3 = {
            zoom: 2,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.1255275,-73.6964801),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map  = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), myOptions);
        map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), myOptions2);  
        map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map3"), myOptions3);  
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div style=" display:inline;" >
    <div style=" float:left; width:50%;" >
        <div id="map1" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px;" ></div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:50%;" >
        <div id="map2" style="width:100%px; height:50%; margin:0px;" ></div>
        <div id="map3" style="width:100%px; height:50%; margin:0px;" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```